# actix-webで早期にレスポンスを返したい。

Tags: rust

Rustのactix-webで条件を満たしたときにエラーレスポンスを返したく以下の通り実装しましたがエラーが出てしまいました。

```
#[post("/backends")]
async fn add_backend(
    pool: web::Data<DbPool>,
    form: web::Json<forms::BackendForm>,
    ) -> Result<HttpResponse, Error>{

    let resp = reqwest::get(&format!("{}/version", form.url))
        .await
        .map_err(|e| {
            eprintln!("{}", e);
            HttpResponse::BadRequest().finish()
        })?;

    if resp.status() != http::StatusCode::OK{
        HttpResponse::BadRequest().finish()
    }

    let version = resp.text()
        .await
        .map_err(|e| {
            eprintln!("{}", e);
            HttpResponse::BadRequest().finish()
        })?;

    if version == ""{
        Ok(HttpResponse::BadRequest().finish())
    }

    let conn = pool.get().expect("cant get db pool");
    let backend = web::block(move || actions::create_backend(&form.name, &form.url, &version, &conn))
        .await
        .map_err(|e| {
            eprintln!("{}", e);
            HttpResponse::InternalServerError().finish()
        })?;

    Ok(HttpResponse::Ok().json(backend))
}



error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:58:9
   |
57 | /     if resp.status() != http::StatusCode::OK{
58 | |         HttpResponse::BadRequest().finish()
   | |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `()`, found struct `actix_http::response::Response`
59 | |     }
   | |_____- expected this to be `()`
   |
   = note: expected unit type `()`
                 found struct `actix_http::response::Response`
help: try adding a semicolon
   |
58 |         HttpResponse::BadRequest().finish();
   |                                            ^
help: consider using a semicolon here
   |
59 |     };
   |      ^

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:69:9
   |
68 | /     if version == ""{
69 | |         Ok(HttpResponse::BadRequest().finish())
   | |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `()`, found enum `std::result::Result`
70 | |     }
   | |_____- expected this to be `()`
   |
   = note: expected unit type `()`
                   found enum `std::result::Result<actix_http::response::Response, _>`
help: try adding a semicolon
   |
69 |         Ok(HttpResponse::BadRequest().finish());
   |                                                ^
help: consider using a semicolon here
   |
70 |     };
   |      ^

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

`finish()`の返り値は`Result<HttpResponse, HttpError>`なのでこれで良いと考えましたがだめでした。
`Ok`で包んでも同様のエラーが出てしまいます。セミコロンをつけることを推奨されていますが、つけるとエラーは消えますが、当然下まで実行されます。このような場合はどのように実装すれば良いのでしょうか。

参考: https://docs.rs/actix-web/0.3.1/actix_web/dev/struct.HttpResponseBuilder.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rustでは単に`Ok(..)`などと式を書いただけでは関数からはリターンしません。早期にリターンさせるためには`return`文が必要です。ただし、関数の最後の式だけは例外で`return`は書かずに式だけを書きます。

以下のように2つの`if`文から返す値に`return`をつけてください。

```
    if resp.status() != http::StatusCode::OK{
        // 関数から早期リターンするために return 文を使う
        return Ok(HttpResponse::BadRequest().finish())
    }

    // 余談だが version == "" の代わりに version.is_empty() としてもよい
    if version.is_empty() {
        // 関数から早期リターン
        return Ok(HttpResponse::BadRequest().finish())
    }
```

これでエラーが直るはずです。

ではなぜ、`if`文以外のところでは`return`文を書かずに関数から早期リターンできていたのでしょうか？　その理由は`?`後置演算子にあります。`?`演算子は引数に`Result`型か`Option`型の値をとり、それらが`Ok(..)`か`Some(..)`なら、包まれている値をアンラップします。また、もしそれらが`Err(..)`か`None`なら、`return`文のように関数から早期リターンします。`?`演算子の働きにより、`return`を書かなくても関数からの早期リターンが行われていたわけです。

もし、Rustのエラー処理全般について詳しく知りたいなら、こちらの和訳ドキュメントが参考になります。
https://doc.rust-jp.rs/the-rust-programming-language-ja/1.9/book/error-handling.html

ただし、このドキュメント（`1.9/book`）は2016年ごろに和訳されたものですので、全体的に内容が古くなっています。`try!()`マクロというものが出てきますが、現在ではそれに代わって`?`後置演算子を使います。`try!(値)`のところは`値?`と読み替えてください。

このドキュメントよりもう少し新しい、2018年ごろの2nd Editionという和訳ドキュメントもあります。Rustの基本について知りたいときは、そちらも参照してください。ただ、残念なことに、2nd Editionではエラー処理についてはあまり詳しく解説されていません。

参考までに、和訳ドキュメントの一覧はこちらにあります。 https://doc.rust-jp.rs/

あと、actix-webに限らずフレームワークやライブラリはそのバージョンによって書き方が変わったりしますので、質問される際に、こんな感じでバージョンに関する情報を載せてもらえると助かります。（今回は別の質問の [回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/63238/14101) を参考にしました）

- Rust 1.41.0
- actix-web 2.0
- reqwest 0.10
- serde 1.0

Comment: 詳しくご回答いただきありがとうございます。今まで古い方のドキュメントを参照していました。その後色々試したところ`Ok(HttpResponse::BadRequest().finish())?;`で動いていたのはそのような理由だったのですか。ライブラリバージョンの旨了解いたしました。次からは記述するようにします。